# Why my function doesn't wait for input?

Tags: c, input

I wrote a function that reads an unknown length string until Enter is pressed and returns a char pointer. When I call the function from inside a switch case, it does not wait for my input.

```
char *get_paths()
{
    unsigned int length_max = 256; /*Initial length of string*/
    unsigned int current_size; 
    current_size = length_max;

    /* Allocating memory for string input */
    char *tmpStr = malloc(length_max);

    /* Simple check to make sure our pointer is not NULL */
    if(tmpStr != NULL)
    {
        int c = EOF; 
        unsigned int i = 0;

        printf("Enter The EXACT or RELATIVE File Paths Separated by a Space: ");

        /* Accept input until Enter key is pressed or user inserts EOF */
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        {
            tmpStr[i] = (char)c;
            ++i;

            /* If memory is filled up, reallocate memory with bigger size */
            if(i == current_size)
            {
                current_size = i + length_max;
                /* realloc does magic */
                tmpStr = realloc(tmpStr, current_size); 
            }
        }

        /* A valid string always end with a '\0' */
        tmpStr[i] = '\0';
        printf("Got it: %s \n", tmpStr); /*TODO: REMOVE;; USED FOR TESTING*/
        return tmpStr; 
    }
}
```

The switch case (I have a char ***ptr = NULL** out of the switch block):

```
/*File input*/
case 1:
    ptr = get_filepaths();
break;
```

**Output:**

> Enter The EXACT or RELATIVE File Paths Separated by a Space: Got it:

Comment: Good on you for commenting your code, but some of your comments are very redundant, for example "Simple check to make sure our pointer is not NULL" is significantly longer than `if(tmpStr != NULL)`, and it doesn't explain anything that the code doesn't explain already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I was able to find to 'somehow' get away with this issue was to add a `getchar()` right after the first `printf()` call. **not sure why this works!**

Comment: You probably have a `scanf()` somewhere that leaves a newline ([read this](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html)). You should clean up after yourself there, not inside the `get_paths()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely running into problems with buffering on `stdout`, which is what `printf` defaults to.  You'll either need to explicitly flush `stdout` or put an newline character at the end of your first `printf` statement in order to force the buffer to flush.  Since there is a newline character at the end of your "Got it" statement, what happens is that both statements (the first one being buffered) print to the output at the same time, since the second statement forces a flushing of the buffer.

Another possibility is that there might already be unread data in `stdin`, and when you call `getchar()` in the `while`-loop, it reads the previously buffered data, hits a newline character, and then exits the loop rather than allowing you to enter new information.  To avoid that issue, do something like `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` in order to consume input up to the next newline (including the newline itself) that's already in the input without worrying about a buffer overflow.

Comment: Added fflush(stdout) after the first printf call, didn't work. Added \n to printf, didn't work. :(

Comment: have you cleared the input before calling `getchar()`? In other words might there have been some other previous input on `stdin` that is being read?

Comment: well i read the user input with scanf in another function in order to use the switch, I tried adding `fflush(stdin)` before `getchar()` is called but it still skips the input.

Comment: So basically right now after the first `printf` I have both `fflush(stdin)` and `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: You might want to put some debug code in that while-loop to see what `getchar()` is returning ...

Comment: ***NEVER*** use `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: Yah, it's better to-do something like `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` ... flushing a stream opened for input invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks @dreamlax, didn't know that. So I debugged the code and when it reaches the while loop, `char c` gets value **10**. then it just jumps to the line after the loop.

Comment: Added `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` after the first printf and it still doesn't work... ffs if i may say.

Comment: Well, there is a newline in the buffer somewhere, that's the ASCII representation of `10` ... maybe there are multiple newlines in the buffer? ... the `scanf()` code I gave you will only gobble up the input to the next newline ... if there are multiple newlines, it won't gobble them up.  You might want to then try `scanf("%*[^]");` ... that should consume everything in the buffer.

Comment: Okay, what about `scanf("%*200c");`? That should eat up to 200 characters, no matter what they are ... not very elegant, but just curious if that is the problem here ...

Comment: Still the same result, `c = 10` right at the start of the loop.

Comment: You're not doing anything counter-intuitive with pipes or modifying the controlling terminal, are you?

Comment: No... I don't even know how to do that :D

Comment: Well, it seems as though you're going to have to check the rest of your code to see why there are extra newlines in the input buffer ... from what you've posted, I cannot see where those newlines would come from.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the help, I managed to fix it more or less after adding a `getchar()` in the function.. but will try to find out why it was causing this problem in the first place.